# How will you install rpm with a shell script and place that into cron

Tags: bash, shell, unix, rpm

How will you install rpm with a shell script and place that into cron .As i have a system that i need to install the package every time the system is rebooted .So need a shell script that will check with an uptime and installed the rpm every time the system is rebooted .

Comment: It seems quite strange to me that you need to reinstall the same package at every reboot. Once it is installed it should remain installed normally...?

Answer (score 1):

```
crontab -e
@reboot rpm -i /path/to/the/package.rpm
```